# datatable inside Highcharts-Pie chart

Tags: highcharts

I want to display the datatable inside Pie chart using Highcharts.I can display the table outside but on exporting the image, datatable is not exported.
So my aim is to display datatable inside the Pie chart.
Refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142153/highcharts-add-text-at-right-side-and-export-all-into-pdf).I was able to partly acheive it.[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sajb/RC9wN/)

But how can i give the column headers and borders to it?

```
$(function () {


   Highcharts.drawTable = function() {

    // user options
    var tableTop = 200,
        colWidth = 60,
        tableLeft = 50,
        rowHeight = 20,
        cellPadding = 2.5,
        valueDecimals = 1,
        valueSuffix = '';

    // internal variables
    var chart = this,
        series = chart.series,
        renderer = chart.renderer,
        cellLeft = tableLeft;

    // draw category labels
    $.each(series, function(serie_index, serie) {
        renderer.text(
            serie.name, 
            cellLeft + cellPadding, 
            tableTop + (serie_index + 1) * rowHeight - cellPadding
        )
        .css({
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        })       
        .add();
    });



        $.each(series[0].data, function(i) {

            renderer.text(
                    series[0].data[i].name, 
                    cellLeft + colWidth - cellPadding, 
                    tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
                )
                .attr({
                    align: 'right'
                })
                .add();
        });
     $.each(series[0].data, function(i) {
            renderer.text(
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(series[0].data[i].y, valueDecimals) + valueSuffix, 
                    150, 
                    tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
                )
                .attr({
                    align: 'left'
                })
                .add();

        });



}




$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        events: {
            load: Highcharts.drawTable
        },
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
        marginBottom: 250
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000',
                connectorColor: '#000000',
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   45.0],
            ['IE',       26.8],
            {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            },
            ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
        ]
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: I exported your example (http://jsfiddle.net/sajb/RC9wN/) and datatable is displayed correctly, so how can I reproduce this problem ?

Comment: i wanted table borders below is the solution suggested by 'ssarabanso'.For headers i will try myself

Answer (score 0):

For the column headers, I don't know. Depends on what you want to do.

As for the borders, since that's SVG, you could draw the borders using `RECT` and `PATH`. Take a look at [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/SpwHF/) of your demo for some crude borders and maybe you can improve on it.

Comment: for single pie chart works fine..had to do adjust a lot according to the length of labels etc...can it be made more dynamic

Comment: More dynamic how? Also, if what you are showing is the same information that is being displayed in the chart, why don't you simply use the legend? Like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/SpwHF/1).